Find Radius of convergence and the function defined by the series
I found this exercise on a book at the library, but I don’t see how to solve it. In fact, I think the exercise is wrong, since I don’t see enough information to solve the problem. Perhaps I am wrong
This is the exercise :  Let be $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^{n}$$
With $c_n \not= 0$ and $c_n = c_{n+4}$. Find the radius of convergence and the function defined by the series.
I don’t see how to solve it. Perhaps I’m right and the exercise don’t make sense? Or I am not looking hard enough? I would appreciate some comments or answers on this.

Collect terms with the same coefficient $c_n$ ...

Yes, I thought that. I am thinking of forming four series and analyzing them separately. Is that a good path?

Pull out $c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3$ and see what series you get.

@RyszardSzwarc Is that suggestion in line with my previous comment?

More generally, suppose
$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^{n}
$
with $c_n=c_{n+m}$
for all $n$
and some fixed $m$.
Then,
for $0 \le k \le m-1$,
$c_k
=c_{k+m}
=c_{k+2m}
...
=c_{k+nm}
$
for all $n$.
Then
$\begin{array}\\
f(x) 
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^{n}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}c_{mn+k}x^{mn+k}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}c_{k}x^{mn+k}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}c_{k}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{mn+k}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}c_{k}x^k\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{mn}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}c_{k}x^k\dfrac1{1-x^m}\\
&= \dfrac1{1-x^m}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}c_{k}x^k\\
\end{array}
$
so the radius of convergence is
$x=1$.
